# Getting the HTML code in response when uploading a file in angularjs from the wamp server and storing on localhost

Tags: html, angularjs, ng-file-upload

I am trying to upload  a file on WAMP(localhost) in angularjs using this link https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload. But When I upload a file on localhost, I am receiving a html response containing HTML code of that folder(In Log).

```
$scope.$watch('file', function (file) {
          console.log("uploading file");
          $scope.upload($scope.file);
        });
         $scope.log = '';
/* optional: set default directive values */
//Upload.setDefaults( {ngf-keep:false ngf-accept:'image/*', ...} );

$scope.upload = function (file) {
    console.log("in upload function");

            Upload.upload({
                url: 'http://localhost/dominodonationform/fileuploads',
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined },
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
                file: file
            }).progress(function (evt) {
                console.log("In progress");
                var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
                $scope.log = 'progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% '+ evt.config.file.name;                               
            }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log("success");
                $timeout(function() {
                    $scope.log = 'file: ' + config.file.name + 'Uploaded , Response: ' + data + '\n' + $scope.log;
                });
            }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.log('error status: ' + status);
                });


};
```

Please help me..

The Response which I get in the log is

```
             Upload Log:
        file: abcd.txtUploaded , Response: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-                     `enter code here`//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
            <html>
           <head>
           <title>Index of /dominodonationform/fileuploads</title>
            </head>
            <body>
             <h1>Index of /dominodonationform/fileuploads</h1>
             <table>
                 <tr><th valign="top"><img src="/icons/blank.gif" alt="             [ICO]"></th><th><a href="?C=N;O=D">Name</a></th><th><a href="?C=M;O=A">Last  modified</a></th><th><a href="?C=S;O=A">Size</a></th><th><a href="?C=D;O=A">Description</a></th></tr>
       <tr><th colspan="5"><hr></th></tr>
          <tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/back.gif" alt="[PARENTDIR]">                      </td><td><a href="/dominodonationform/">Parent Directory</a></td><td>&nbsp;</td>  <td align="right">  - </td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
        <tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/folder.gif" alt="[DIR]"></td>  <td><a href="New%20folder/">New folder/</a>            </td><td align="right">2015-08-10 10:03  </td><td align="right">  - </td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><th colspan="5"><hr></th></tr>
 </table>
  <address>Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 Server at localhost Port    80</address>
     </body></html>

     progress: 100% abcd.txt
```

Please help me.
I will replace the URL with original one after it works.

Comment: Can i see your php code?

Comment: No write now, der is no code on server side...I am using the above code to upload a file using Wamp Server and trying to upload the file on given url on localhost...

Comment: Without writing php code how you can upload file?

Comment: I am responsible for front end.I thought it will get uploaded without server side as I am uploading in localhost....

Comment: Your server need to handle a file upload at that url, but it is just serving an html page.

Comment: Server side code is needed for that in localhost or in live. both condition have needed server code